# How works exactly the option disable App notifications

Tags: applications, notifications, task-management

Some Apps like Facebook also when aren't used slow down the device because of their associated autostart tasks.
In android settings in Apps section there is the option to enable or disable the notification.

This works only on notification or disable also the associated task completely?

How works exactly?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only hides the notification when the app creates it. It doesn't affect what the app might do in the background or stop the app spending battery and data to create it in the first place.

Comment: What a pity! Android needs a way to disable autostart task

Comment: It really doesn't, unless you like your apps crashing or not working in confusing ways. If you don't like the way the app works, don't install it, and be sure to tell the developer why.

Comment: Not exactly. I need some apps but not their notifications and when are installed awfully slow down my device, with a native way to disable their associated autostart task this problem is solved at the root